# SQL query using LIKE and Union

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-like

I'm trying to generate a list of friends for users to invite to an event, however only if they're not already attending the event or have a pending invite request.

The way my friends system works, there are 3 columns in the table. userid1, userid2, and friendstatus. The user who sent the request goes into column 1(`userid1`), the user who received the request goes into column 2(`userid2`). Since the user creating the event could be in either column, I use the following query when adding friends to the event.

```
//this block is finding friends from column1
SELECT userid1 as friendID 
FROM friends 
WHERE userid2 = $myUsername AND friendstatus = 1
UNION 
// this section is finding friends from column 2
SELECT userid2 as friendId 
FROM friends 
WHERE userid1 = $myUsername AND friendstatus = 1
```

I set the userid as friendID because this query generates a list which I then use checkboxes for (which the value is determined from)

However, once the event is created if users attending it want to add more friends, I need a way to pull their friends but only if those friends are not alread attending or have a pending request. 
The column in my events table for users attending is called `acceptedInvites` and the column  for pending requests is in `inviteRequest`.

So, here's the query that I can't get to work. If the `userid` is in the `acceptedInvites` or `inviteRequest` DO NOT select that value

```
//this section is finding friends from column1
SELECT 
    events.inviteRequest, 
    events.acceptedInvites, 
    friends.userid1 as friendID 
FROM friends 
LEFT JOIN events on 
    friends.userid1 NOT LIKE '%events.inviteRequest%' AND 
    friends.userid1 NOT LIKE '%events.acceptedInvites%'
WHERE friends.userid2 = $userid AND friends.friendstatus = 1 
UNION 
//this section is finding friends from column 2
SELECT users.userid2 as friendId 
FROM friends 
LEFT JOIN events on 
    friends.userid2 NOT LIKE '%events.inviteRequest%' AND 
    friends.userid2 NOT LIKE '%events.acceptedInvites%'
WHERE friends.userid1 = $userid AND friends.friendstatus = 1
```

For example:

**friends table**
columns are friend1, friend2 and friendstatus

(row 1) userid1:1   userid2:userid2   friendstatus:1

(row 2) userid1:3   userid2:1   friendstatus:1

-userid1 is friends with userid1 and userid3. As I stated above, the user in userid1

**events table**
columns used are acceptedInvites inviteRequests

(row 1) acceptedInvites: "1~2"  inviteRequests : " "

-userid1 and userid2 are attending the event, no pending invites

Based on this, if userid1 wants to add more friends only userid3 will show up.

Comment: You better provide some data and expect result so that everyone can take a look quickly and help.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure what you mean. Are you asking me to also list the tables?

Comment: No. Post a *sample* of the data, and a *sample* of what you're trying to get from it with your query. As written, your SQL is absolutely meaningless; your `LIKE` expressions is using column names between the wildcards as *content*, so unless the actual value stored in `friends.userid2` could be something like `123events.inviterequest456`, it would never work (everything would be `NOT LIKE` it).

Comment: I edited it, I hope this helps. I tried to make it as clear as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant the following:

`events.inviteRequest NOT LIKE '%' + friends.userid1 + '%'`

This would be better, but wouldn't be correct either. How are you separating userIds in your `inviteRequest`? Assuming they are comma-separated, the following condition returns `false` even though userid 3 is not in the list:

```
'23,35,35' NOT LIKE '%3%'
```

See my point? A trick to fix this is to add a comma to both sides of `inviteRequest`, then you'll have something like:

```
',23,35,35,' NOT LIKE '%,3,%'  -- Note the commas around 3.
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: You have `'%events.inviteRequest%'` which doesn't make sense to me because you are placing a column name inside a string. I think you at least meant '%' + events.inviteRequest + '%'. See the difference?

Comment: I do see what you're saying and changed it. Still no luck.